# Rounding error with microseconds using as.POSIXlt

Tags: r, datetime, time, posixct

I find some strange behaviour from `as.POSIXlt` that I am unable to explain, I am hoping someone else can. In investigating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16179104/1478381) I found that sometimes the fractional part of a second would be rounded incorrectly

For example, the numbers below represent a particular second since the epoch has begun, with the last 6 digits being the fractional part of the second, so the fraction of a second on the first number should be .645990.

```
# Generate sequence of integers to represent date/times
times <- seq( 1366039619645990 , length.out = 11 )
options(scipen=20)
times
 [1] 1366039619645990 1366039619645991 1366039619645992 1366039619645993 1366039619645994 1366039619645995
 [7] 1366039619645996 1366039619645997 1366039619645998 1366039619645999 1366039619646000

# Convert to date/time with microseconds 
options(digits.secs = 6 )
as.POSIXlt( times/1e6, tz="EST", origin="1970-01-01") + 5e-7
 [1] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645990 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645991 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645992 EST"
 [4] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645993 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645994 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645995 EST"
 [7] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645996 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645997 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645998 EST"
[10] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645999 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.646000 EST"
```

I found that I have to add a small increment, equal to half the minimum change in time to get correct representation of the fractional part of a second, otherwise rounding errors occur. And it works just fine if I run `as.POSIXlt` on a sequence of numbers as above, however if I try to convert one number, namely the one that should end in .645999 then the number of truncated to .645 and I do not know why!

```
# Now just convert the date/time that should end in .645999
as.POSIXlt( times[10]/1e6, tz="EST", origin="1970-01-01") + 5e-7
[1] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645 EST"
```

Compare the 10th element in the vector returned by `as.POSIXlt` with the single element equivalent above. What is happening?

Session info:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.0-41 sp_1.0-5     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2     lattice_0.20-13 tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: On my machine it drops all the decimals of `times` when doing `times/1e6`. In fact I get `2013-04-15 10:26:59 EST` 11 times...

Comment: @Michele thanks! - you have shown me I am missing one vital piece of code in my example - adding now!!

Comment: @Michele please can you try again? Run `options( digits.secs = 6 )` first.

Comment: This is a formatting issue, most thoroughly discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7726034/271616).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich thanks for the link - extremely informative. Shall I close this as a dupe then? I was looking at POSIXlt which is why I didn't see this title with POSIXct

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I think that *this* is a rounding issue. `format.POSIXlt` doesn't work as expected because of inaccuracy in the way the threshold for rounding a number calcualted. If we run the command `sprintf( "%.20f" , abs(secs[2] - round(secs,5)))` it gives `[1] "0.00000099999999991773"` which is < 0.000001 (see in answer below for how that subsequently affects printing). Does that make sense?

Comment: @SimonO101: there's no "threshold" for rounding a number. What you're seeing is the effect of floating point precision: `sprintf("%22.20f",secs)`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I know - see my answer below! But there is a *threshold*  (I do't explain myself very well I admit) - in format.POSIXlt , a number is rounded to a maximum of 6 digits, no matter how many decimal places you give it to (also see below)

Comment: @SimonO101: Oh, I see; you're referring to the threshold in `format.POSIXlt`.  That's what I meant by it being a formatting issue.  The actual underlying number is correct, it just does not print correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a rounding issues, whereby significant digits of the fractional second are discarded. The *offending*(?) code is in the format methods for objects of class `POSIXlt`, namely `format.POSIXlt` which is used by `print.POSIXlt`.

If we use the two values below as an example, `format.POSIXlt` uses the following line which I have wrapped in an sapply to test the absolute value of the difference between the fractional seconds rounded to successively greater number of digits.

```
secs <- c( 59.645998 , 59.645999 )
sapply( seq_len(np) - 1L , function(x) abs(secs - round(secs, x)) )
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
[1,] 0.354002 0.045998 0.004002 0.000002 0.000002 0.000002
[2,] 0.354001 0.045999 0.004001 0.000001 0.000001 0.000001
```

As you can see when the seconds are .xxx999 any rounding to 3 or more digits gives 0.000001 which affects the printing thus:

```
# the number of digits used for the fractional seconds is gotten here
np <- getOption("digits.secs")

# and the length of digits to be printed is controlled in this loop
for (i in seq_len(np) - 1L) if (all(abs(secs - round(secs, 
                i)) < 0.000001)) {
                np <- i
                break
            }
```

This is because 0.000001 as actually found in the above method is:

```
sprintf( "%.20f" , abs(secs[2] - round(secs,5)))
[1] "0.00000099999999991773"            

# In turn this is used to control the printing of the fractional seconds            
if (np == 0L) 
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        else paste0("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", np)
```

So the fractional seconds get truncated to only 3 decimal places because of the test used in rounding. I think if the test value in the for loop was set to 5e-7 this issue would disappear.

When the result returned is a vector of `POSIXlt` objects a different print method must be getting called.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got a proper answer (keep looking into it) but I thought this was interesting:

```
times <- seq( 1366039619645990 , length.out = 11 )
# Convert to date/time wz="EST", origin="1970-01-01") + 5e-7
options(digits.secs = 6 )

test <- as.POSIXlt( times/1e6, tz="EST", origin="1970-01-01") + 5e-7

test1[1] <- NULL
for(i in 1:11)
  test1[i] <- as.POSIXlt(times[i]/1e6, tz="EST", origin="1970-01-01") + 5e-7

> identical(test, test1)
[1] TRUE
```

BTW, in single statements I got the same result as you...

```
> test
 [1] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645990 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645991 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645992 EST"
 [4] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645993 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645994 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645995 EST"
 [7] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645996 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645997 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645998 EST"
[10] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645999 EST" "2013-04-15 10:26:59.646000 EST"
> test[10]
[1] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645 EST"
> as.POSIXlt( times[10]/1e6, tz="EST", origin="1970-01-01") + 5e-7
[1] "2013-04-15 10:26:59.645 EST"
```

Looking at the last two statements, it seems that this issue is mainly related to displaying the single value rather then a vector. But even in this case it would be a truncation, probably via `floor`, not a rounding.

Comment: +1 for making me see it must be an issue of rounding or truncation